# Build Error after creating project with nodejs example provided by openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, web-deployment, web-deployment-project, openshift-nextgen

I am trying to create a project on openshift for the first time, but there seems to be a problem with it. I am following the exact steps provided here : https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/basic_walkthrough.html.

I am using the sample project provided by openshift.(Link to sample project: https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex )

Still every time I am getting build error.

I have my github username with  below.

The logs are :

```
    Pulling image "registry.ops.openshift.com/openshift3/nodejs-010-rhel7@sha256:03e412c10b611503becdfgh6b0d6392c6btu6790hgf17de88709e055da2be723" ...
    Pulling image "registry.ops.openshift.com/openshift3/nodejs-010-rhel7@sha256:03e412c10b611503beca1285b0d6392c6b52bfe2a1f17de88709e055da2be723" ...
    Cloning "https://github.com/<github-username>/nodejs-ex" ...
        Commit: 343689f74d71911bdg450hd0bdb5307ea65ce426 (Merge pull request #83 from guangxuli/fix_branch)
        Author: Ben Parees <bparees@users.noreply.github.com>
        Date:   Mon Dec 12 08:26:46 2016 -0500

    ---> Installing application source ...
    ---> Building your Node application from source
    npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
    npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble: line 51:    17 Killed                  npm install

    error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.ops.openshift.com/openshift3/nodejs-010-rhel7@sha256:03e412c104567503beca1285b0gh392c6b52bfe2a1f17de88709e055da2be723
```

Comment: I had similar issue with **Django**. After few days the problem automatically disappeared. This may be due the **OpenShift Server** itself since it's in Developing Stage.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have similar too right now